How do I enable syntax highlighting for Lua in Eclipse recent versions (2024-03)?
I´m not being able to find any lua syntax plugins for Eclipse. The only known one is discontinued (LDT - Lua Development Tools).
Some people were able to install it using the process described in this page.
The problem is DLTK plugin that isn't installed in newer eclipse versions. So some people installed a former version and it worked.
When I tried this Eclipse refused installation saying I already had a newer version installed, probably because I'm using WWD that uses it.
Anyway I don't need a full IDE for lua as I will be using it only for creating Redis scripts. I just need a proper syntax highlighter.
Anyone knows an Eclipse plugin that has Lua syntax support besides LDT or how can I install LDT in newer Eclipses ?

The TextMate Language Pack provides syntax highlighting for Lua (see here) which can be installed via Help > Install New Software... working with the update site https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/. Please note that LDT is open source and just needs someone to update it.

Worked... thanks. Don´t you want to create a answer so I can accept it ?

The TextMate Language Pack provides syntax highlighting for Lua (see here) and for other languages and formats. It can be installed via Help > Install New Software... working with the update site https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest/.
Please note that the Lua Development Tools (LDT) which provides better support for Lua is currently looking for new contributors/committers. Otherwise it is likely to be archived soon.
